# Measurement and Unit, are these the best words to use to describe things like 100mg, 1ea, 4tab

Tags: word-choice

I have a spreadsheet that has some data concatenated and I want to split it into appropriate fields.

METHADONE HCL **5**MG TAB UD
POTASSIUM CHLORIDE **20**MEQ PACKET
MUPIROCIN 2% NASAL **1**GM OINT

I am thinking that:
the 5, the 20, and the 1 are *measurements*
the MG, MEQ, and GM are *units*
the TAB, PACKET, and OINT are *forms*

Is there a better word to use for any of these? For example, *measurement* might not be appropriate because *measurement* might imply both a number and a unit of measure (eg if someone asks for a measurement you don't reply "four," you say "four somethings.")

EDIT - these are descriptions of discrete medications. So *Methadone 5 mg tablets*. I might have a bottle of thirty 5 mg tablets. This is why "qty" is not ideal - it's being used for another label (the thirty).

To explain more about the problem - this is part of an inventory calculation. Right now I have these drug descriptions. In the example of methadone, if I give you "30," I need to be clear that I'm giving you 30x5 mg (as opposed to 30mg). The reason is that destruction is also tracked. So if a patient consumes 20 of the 30 tablets, we have ten tablets to account for. If the ten are destroyed, they can be destroyed as 10 tablets or 50 mg.

So I could rephrase the question as: in the phrase "**Thirty (30) 5mg Methadone Tablets**"

**Thirty** is *Qty*.
**Methadone** is *Drug* or *Item* or *Whatever*.
**Tablets** is *Form*.
**mg** is *Unit* (?) - is it? **Perhaps *metric* is better**?
**5** is *??????*

Comment: I would call the number the quantity.

Comment: @medica 'dosage' and 'mass/weight of one unit' ('unit' in the sense of 'item') may not be the same.

Comment: The 5 is "*Strength*" : http://www.drugs.com/ibuprofen-images.html